# GeoServer Setup - Geometry and Labels

Tags: openlayers, wms, layers

Setting up data in GeoServer and have points of interest with names.  I'd like to show them in OpenLayers with a checkbox to turn labels off and on.  I know I can do this with separate layers, but I was not sure if there was a best way to set that up in GeoServer.

Do I need two layers pointing to the same PostGIS table with different styles, or is there a way to do it without two layers in GeoServer?

All the [Style Cookbook](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/index.html) stuff I've seen seems to focus on one layer being presented.

We will probably show them as WMS at first and/or MVT in the future, so mostly focused on WMS output for now but open to MVT/Vector ideas too!

Comment: Two layers is probably the best approach.

Comment: As an alternative, set an equality filter around the rule with labels, where one side of the comparison is static, and the other uses the "env" function. When you want to turn labels off, set the env variables in your request so that they don't match. Not a thing of beauty, but allows to use a single layer if you want to.